# English for "Wer austeilt muss auch einstecken können."

Tags: german-to-english, phrase

Is there an English equivalent to the German idiom in the title? It is used to remind someone not mincing their words to be sporting when someone else responds in kind.

Comment: Not entirely sure this is the right forum for this question.Feel free to close or move.

Comment: The community can close, but not migrate, so it is better if you look for a suitable SE site yourself.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a suggestion?

Comment: I don’t know how well the question would be received there (you would probably  have to explain the German a bit more at leat), there are https://english.stackexchange.com/ and https://ell.stackexchange.com/. You could check https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proverb-requests to see what got good answers on ELU and what not.

Comment: That is very helpful. Thans a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What goes around, comes around.

Comment: I reasked the question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/575981/435095) in case you want to repost your answer.

Comment: "If you can't take it, don't give it". Oder völlig anders: "If you can't do the time, don't do the crime".